# Vim's "tabf + TAB" to list only certain file types?

Tags: vim

When you type `:tabf MyFile` and press `TAB`, Vim list's you all of the files starting with `MyFile`. I want it to list only files of certain type, for example ".txt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can set the `suffixes` option to assign relative priority between filetypes.
- You can use `wildignore` to exclude some filetypes from tab completion altogether

Answer (score 1):

If you type

:tabf *.txt

and then <kbd>tab</kbd> it already works in the way you want. At least in Vim 7.3. As a bonus hint, on the command line try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. It will show only the matched files. See [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-D) for further information.